# CriteriaBuilder Hibernate. Как использовать JOIN?

Tags: hibernate

Наверное ребята, которые пишут документации очень сонные все время, так как не понятно почему всегда на половине примера все обрывается.
Вот пример из доков, вроде и пример, а с другой стороны кусок бестолкового, недописанного кода:

```
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Pet> Pet_ = m.entity(Pet.class);
EntityType<Owner> Owner_ = m.entity(Owner.class);

Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
Join<Owner, Address> address = cq.join(Pet_.owners).join(Owner_.addresses);
```

Ну написали они как вызвать джойн, а что делать с ним? Что это вообще такое address? Что это за тип такой ? Куда его помещать ? КАК УКАЗАТЬ, ПО КАКОМУ ПОЛЮ Я ХОЧУ СДЕЛАТЬ JOIN? Или этот интерфейс наделен интеллектом и он сам знает как и по какому полю когда джойнить? 
Кто сталкивался с типобезопасными запросами и джойнами, приведите пример как закончить написания полноценного джойн запроса, чтобы указать, что я хочу джойник по полю айди, потому что сил больше нету играть в эти загадки и отгадайки с документациями гибернатов.

**Update 1**: Только, что нашел пример с построением записей в критериа, с офф доков гибернейт.

Example 9.10. Example with Collections

```
CriteriaQuery<Person> personCriteria = builder.createQuery( Person.class );
Root<Person> personRoot = person.from( Person.class );
Join<Person,Order> orders = personRoot.join( Person_.orders );
Join<Order,LineItem> orderLines = orders.join( Order_.lineItems );
```

Это все... это весь пример. Замечательно. Зачем он нужен? Что я из него узнал? Да ничего не узнал. Это просто половина незаконченного кода. Возможно у кого-то есть достойный источник где можно изучить типобезопасные запросы?

**Update 2**: Ответ на вопрос, если у кого-то будут сложности с созданием типобезопасных запросов с использованием JOIN.

```
@Override
public List<Menu> getAllFromPlace(Long id){
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Menu> query = builder.createQuery(Menu.class);
    Root<Place> root = query.from(Place.class);
    Join<Place,Menu> menu = root.join(Place_.menus);
    query.select(menu).where(builder.equal(root.get(Place_.id), id));
    List<Menu> menus = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    return menus;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Предположим мы имеем сущности, между которыми есть отношение `"Один ко Многим"` - `Man - Car`, соответственно:

```
class Man
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

class Car
{
   public virtual string Brend { get; set; }

   public virtual Man Man { get; set; }
}
```

Для выполнения `Join` в `Nhibernate` у Вас есть несколько вариантов.

**Вариант 1**

В самом простом случае, достаточно вызвать метод `Fetch()`, в котором можно указать связанную сущность, которую нужно загрузить вместе с основной.

В нашем случае, при получении из БД сущностей `Car` будут загружены связанные с ней сущности `Man`, данный LINQ запрос как раз-таки будет преобразован в SQL запрос с инструкцией `Join`.

```
var cars = session.Query<Car>().Where(p => p.Brend == "BMW").Fetch(p => p.Man).ToList();
```

---

**Вариант 2**

Использовать SQL запрос.

```
// Пишем SELECT.
var query = "SELECT * FROM Cars INNER JOIN People
             ON Cars.ManID" = People.ID 
             WHERE Cars.Brend = 'BMW'";

// Выполняем его через Nhibernate.
var cars = session.CreateSQLQuery(query).List<Car>();
```

Comment: мне как раз этот вариант нужно было заменить типобезопасными запросами, я уже обновил вопрос с правильным ответом)

Comment: Прошу обратить внимание, что вопрос был задан про `Hibernate`, а ответили вы про `NHibernate`. Библиотеки, конечно же, похожи - но языки-то разные! :)

Comment: Pavel, я уже потом заметил это, но API у них идентичны.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю теоретически, поскольку сам я с `Hibernate` не работал. (Кроме того, практическое решение вы уже, кажется, нашли)

> Ну написали они как вызвать джойн, а что делать с ним? Что это вообще такое address? Что это за тип такой ? Куда его помещать ? КАК УКАЗАТЬ, ПО КАКОМУ ПОЛЮ Я ХОЧУ СДЕЛАТЬ JOIN? Или этот интерфейс наделен интеллектом и он сам знает как и по какому полю когда джойнить?

Без паники. Посмотрите на запрос: в нем вы указываете такие вещи как `Pet_.owners` и `Owner_.addresses`. Именно по ним и берутся поля, по которым делается join.

Когда вы создаете ассоциацию (связь) между двумя сущностями - вы указываете ее тип, навигационные свойства и ее отображение в базе данных.

Так, у каждого объекта `Pet` есть коллекция `owners`. Дальше я не знаю точно - но, по логике, у объекта `Owner` должна быть коллекция `pets`. В таком случае, эта связь - связь типа "много-ко-многим". Такие связи отображаются в БД на дополнительную таблицу.

Соответственно, когда в запросе делается `.join(Pet_.owners)` - в БД уходит *два* джойна с этой самой промежуточной таблицей, как-то так:

```
Pets p
JOIN Pets_Owners po ON p.Id = po.PetId
JOIN Owners o ON o.Id = po.OwnerId
```

Альтернативный вариант - когда у объекта `Owner` может быть только один `Pet`. В таком случае эта связь - односторонняя типа "один-ко-многим", и для нее назначается отдельное поле в таблице `Owners`, которое является внешним ключем.

В таком случае, когда в запросе делается `.join(Pet_.owners)` - в БД уходит простой join по указанному в ассоциации внешнему ключу:

```
Pets p
JOIN Owners o ON o.PetId = p.Id
```

---

Таким образом, при работе с ORM вообще не следует думать о каких-то "полях" - если только БД не унаследованная, то вся ее структура можэет быть целиком создана силами ORM именно в том виде, в котором надо.

Работая с ORM, следует думать в терминах ассоциаций и навигационных свойств.